# So, there is no shortcut in applying authorize attribute in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I have a really large system that requires authentication, I find it tedious to annotate my  controllers / action methods as [Authorize]. Fluent Security seems to be a good idea as suggested by [Jon Gallaway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way), but we still have to take care of each and every controller or action method that requires authentication.  I just wonder if there is a better approach, something even better than fluent security. Any thoughts?

Comment: Its good to have a layer super type pattern always and  have controllers with similar behaviour having a common parent where we can apply Authorise filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `[Authorize]` to a `BaseAuthorizedController:Controller` class. Then for classes that you know have locked down functions. Deriving from this class will force all class members to adhere to the base classes `[Authorize]` attribute and you need not worry about each and every function.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Authorize filter works the way it works and I don't think there's an out-of-the-box solution for what you are trying to achieve. If I haven't got your question wrong, you want all your controllers and controller actions to be protected from unauthorized access by default, without taking any extra steps to annotate each controller/action with the Authorize filter, right? If so, maybe a good solution would be to create your own Controller by extending the Controller class. Then have it override the `OnAuthorization` method. For example...

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

Then, you might want to check whether the `AllowAnonymous` filter has been specified or not

Comment: This is cool. Same effect as that of @Irb. I didn't know that the controller class has OnAuthorization method. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it does, and the most important part is that the `OnAuthorization` method is a virtual method (can be overridden). Furthermore, you gain access immediately to the current context where you can access the `Request`, `Response` object, cookies and the whole shebang. You can even make "high-level business logic" decisions and perform redirects based on the authentication status of the current user